# filtered list of files in a directory

Tags: csv, python-3.x

I have files in the directory with the following naming convention arriving daily and wish to filter a list of file to interoperate the data.  I have been playing with regular and finding it difficult match the file I want to filter.

```
import re

fnames = ["JEExport_20150501-20150531_Credit-Balance-Adjustment-Applied_20150531183249.csv",
        "JEExport_20150501-20150531_External-Credit-Balance-Payment_20150531183254.csv",
        "JEExport_20150501-20150531_External-Payment_20150531183251.csv",
        "JEExport_20150501-20150531_Invoice-Item_20150531183255.csv",
        "JEExport_20150501-20150531_Invoice-Item-Adjustment_20150531183304.csv"
        "JEExport_20150501-20150531_Invoice-Item-Adjustment-Tax_20150531183313.csv",
        "JEExport_20150501-20150531_Taxation-Item_20150531183240.csv"]

for element in fnames:    
    m = re.match("[A-Za-z]+\-[A-Za-z]+|-[A-Za-z]+", element)    
    if m == 'Invoice-Item-Adjustment':
        print(element) # do something
```

Comment: That isn't how regexes work in Python. re.match() returns a regex MatchObject (or nothing), `m` will never equal a string. https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match and https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need regex. Does this work?

```
fnames = ["JEExport_20150501-20150531_Credit-Balance-Adjustment-Applied_20150531183249.csv",
        "JEExport_20150501-20150531_External-Credit-Balance-Payment_20150531183254.csv",
        "JEExport_20150501-20150531_External-Payment_20150531183251.csv",
        "JEExport_20150501-20150531_Invoice-Item_20150531183255.csv",
        "JEExport_20150501-20150531_Invoice-Item-Adjustment_20150531183304.csv",
        "JEExport_20150501-20150531_Invoice-Item-Adjustment-Tax_20150531183313.csv",
        "JEExport_20150501-20150531_Taxation-Item_20150531183240.csv"]

for element in fnames:        
    if 'Invoice-Item-Adjustment' in element:
        print(element) # do something

JEExport_20150501-20150531_Invoice-Item-Adjustment_20150531183304.csv
JEExport_20150501-20150531_Invoice-Item-Adjustment-Tax_20150531183313.csv
```

Comment: No it won't work the other one included. JEExport_20150501-20150531_Invoice-Item-Adjustment-Tax_20150531183313.csv

Comment: OK what if you change it to `'Invoice-Item-Adjustment_'`?

Comment: OK So I don't understand what you're trying to do. What file names do you want returned?

Comment: JEExport_20150501-20150531_Invoice-Item-Adjustment_20150531183304.csv

Comment: Then use if `'Invoice-Item-Adjustment_' in element`

Comment: By the way copy my whole code before you run, you're missing a comma in your fnames array in your original question.